# Pyodbc Connection Error

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc, netezza, unixodbc

## Code

This is the code that I have entered using python 2.6 in linux Red Hat 64bit

```
import pyodbc

print pyodbc.dataSources()

print "Connecting via ODBC"

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=localhost;PORT=5480;DATABASE=Database;UID=santiago;PWD=ha123;")
```

## Error

This is the true error I received when running pyodbc. I don't know what this language is or what it means?

```
{'ODBC': '', 'NetezzaSQL': '/usr/local/nz_7.2.0.3/lib64/libnzodbc.so'}
Connecting via ODBC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 41, in <module>
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER{NetezzaSQL};SERVER=localhost;PORT=5480;DATABASE=Database;UID=santiago;PWD=ha123;")
pyodbc.Error: ('H00', '[H00] [unixODBC]Sre n/rpr trbtsaeepy\xc8 (33) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

## obdcinst.ini

This is the obdcinst  file used

```
[ODBC Drivers]
NetezzaSQL = Installed

[NetezzaSQL]
Driver           = /usr/local/nz_7.2.0.3/lib64/libnzodbc.so
Setup            = /usr/local/nz_7.2.0.3/lib64/libnzodbc.so
APILevel         = 1
ConnectFunctions = YYN
Description      = Netezza ODBC driver
DriverODBCVer    = 03.51
DebugLogging     = false
LogPath          = /tmp
UnicodeTranslationOption = utf8
CharacterTranslationOption = all
PreFetch         = 256
Socket           = 16384
```

## obdc.ini

This the odbc configuration file used

```
;
;  odbc.ini
;
[ODBC Data Sources]
NZSQL = NetezzaSQL


[NetezzaSQL]
;Path of a driver used for database connection
Driver                = /usr/local/nz_7.2.0.3/lib64/libnzodbc.so

;A decription used to identify the database connection properties.
Description           = NetezzaSQL ODBC

;The name of a machine or IP address where the database is located.
Servername            = 127.0.0.1

;The port number to connect.
Port                  = 5480

;The name of a database.
Database              = dev

;The name of a valid user.
Username              = guest

;The password for  the user.
Password              = password

;Only Select SQL statements will be allowed if this field is checked.
ReadOnly              = false

;When this option is enabled and the application bindtype is same as   backend
;datatype the query performance will be faster.Query performance gain will be achieved 
;only for single select statements (not for batch queries).It also works in case when
;application bind type is different than backend datatype but there are some restrictions on it.
FastSelect            = false

;When set to true, system tables will be included in the available table list.
ShowSystemTables      = false

;When set to true, use old (2.5) functionality for returning schemas in  SQLTables.
LegacySQLTables       = false

;Specifies login timeout in seconds.
LoginTimeout          = 0

;Specifies query timeout in seconds.
QueryTimeout          = 0

;Specifies date format as follows -
; 1: YMD
; 2: MDY
; 3: DMY
DateFormat            = 1

;When selected, driver treats SQL_C_NUMERIC buffers as SQL_C_CHAR   buffers.
NumericAsChar         = false

;Return SQL_BIT as "1"/"0" when char.
SQLBitOneZero         = false

;When enabled, replaces all occurences of CRLF, CR and LF with a single space.
StripCRLF             = false

;Specifies level of security on the system
securityLevel         = preferredUnSecured

;Name of the Root CA certificate.
caCertFile            =

;Specifies maximum errors allowed. 0 value means no limit on  loadMaxErrors value.
;loadMaxErrors         = 1

;If value is true, it rounds the data of numeric columns whose precision  exceeds the precision defined.
;loadRoundFraction     = 0


[ODBC]
IANAAppCodePage=4
InstallDir=/opt/odbc32v51
Trace=0
TraceDll=/opt/odbc32v51/lib/odbctrac.so
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
UseCursorLib=0
```

If anything else is needed to determine solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what the error means as I don't recognize the language either.  However, the Netezza ODBC port is 5480, while you specify 5668 in your connection method.  Also, is the database you really want to connect to is actually named "Database"?

Comment: I changed the attributes since it is not good to put private information on the web, but I got the correct database in and 5480 is included in the original code. I ran the same code in windows using python with original attributes and it worked, but on my linux machine it is not working.

Comment: You might want to change it consistently throughout otherwise it looks like a configuration/parameter error (see the port you specify later in your sample ODBC.ini)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. Do you think this could be a python interpreter issue?